# Does a factor model always include traded portfolios or can it also be other variables?

Tags: factor-models

Does a factor model always include traded portfolios or can it also be other variables? For example, a four factor model of

$R^e_{it}=\alpha_i+\beta^{M}_{i}\text{MKT}_t+\beta^{SMB}_{i}\text{SMB}_t+\beta^{HML}_{i}\text{HML}_t+\beta^{CPI}\text{CPI}_t$, where we have the typical Fama-French three factor model augmented with values of Consumer Price Index (So not a traded portfolio). Can we test individual (5x5 size/value) portfolio $\alpha s$ for such a model or does it not work this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A famous (APT) factor pricing model was developed by [Chen, Ross and Roll (1986)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2352710?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents). The model suggests
$$R_{i,t}=a_i + \beta_{i,MP}MP_t + \beta_{i,UI}UI_t + \beta_{i,DEI}DEI_t+\beta_{i,UPR}UPR_t+\beta_{i,UTS}UTS_t+\varepsilon_{i,t},$$
where $\varepsilon_{i,t}$ is an idiosyncratic term. The factors are not all tradable returns. $UPR$ and $UTS$ are, but $MP$, $UI$ and $DEI$ are not. Nonetheless, you can have these factors in your model and use, for example, [Fama and MacBeth (1973)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1831028?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) regressions to estimate the risk premiums. The individual factors are

- Monthly growth in industrial  production
  $$MP_t = \ln\left(\frac{IP_t}{IP_{t-1}}\right)$$
- Unexpected inflation
  $$UI_t=I_t-\mathbb{E}_{t-1}[I_t]$$
- Change in expected inflation
  $$DEI_t=\mathbb{E}_t[I_{t+1}]-\mathbb{E}_{t-1}[I_t]$$
- Default risk premium
  $$UPR_t=\text{Baa or under bond returns}_t - \text{Long-term government bond returns}_t$$
- Term structure premium
  $$UTS_t= \text{Long-term government bond returns}_t - \text{Treasuary-bill rate}_{t-1}$$

Sometimes, a researcher may want to use tradable portfolios. [Chan, Karceski, and Lakonishok (1998, JFQA)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-financial-and-quantitative-analysis/article/abs/risk-and-return-from-factors/08AEBF6C0CD09C1C04EF2477AAFDFA5C) or [Cooper and Priestley (2011, JFE)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304405X11000353) are examples who follow this approach and describe how to obtain mimicking portfolios for the CRR factors.

In doubt, it's always good to see what [John Cochrane](https://www.johnhcochrane.com/asset-pricing) has to say.

> *The pricing implications of any model can be equivalently represented
> by its factor-mimicking portfolio. If there is any measurement error in a set
> of economic variables driving $m$, the factor-mimicking portfolios for the
> true $m$ will price assets better than an estimate of $m$ that uses the measured
> macroeconomic variables.*

> *Thus, it is probably not a good idea to evaluate economically interesting
> models with statistical horse races against models that use portfolio returns
> as factors. Economically interesting models, even if true and perfectly
> measured, will just equal the performance of their own factor-mimicking
> portfolios, even in large samples. Add any measurement error, and the economic model will underperform its own factor-mimicking portfolios.*